# PHP Mailer SMTP Error: Data not accepted

Tags: php, smtp

i have a strange problem. I try to send a mail with a pdf document as attachment with php mailer. The script works fine, as long i call it in the browser. When i try to call it from console inside a batch, i'm getting SMTP Error: Data not accepted.
My system is a windows 2008 R2 Server with xampp. The only difference is the user context. When i call the script in the browser, i guess apache will call my script and the apache service is running as lokal system. When i'm starting the batch file the script will probably be called by the user i'm logged in with right ?

Maybe someone could help me out with that problem :)

Greets Mike

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username = "username";           
    $mail->Password = "password";           
    $mail->SetFrom('mymail@outlook.com', 'Me');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("mymail@mydomain.com", "Me");
```

This is my batch:

```
C:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\bericht\sendMail2.php
```

Comment: What have you tried in your code?

Comment: When you're calling the script from console you take apache out of the stack. Instead of the PHP-CGI executable you make use of the PHP-CLI executable. You don't carry over any browser sessions to your command line. They both usually have different configs. If you could provide us with code we will be able to help you out.

Comment: Don't put code in the commands, edit your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username = "username";           
$mail->Password = "password";           
$mail->SetFrom('mymail@outlook.com', 'Me');
$mail->AddReplyTo("mymail@mydomain.com", "Me");
```

This is my batch:

```
C:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\bericht\sendMail2.php
```

Comment: Please put the code in your original question by using the edit function. You can't use answers to extend your previous question.